# Mysql maximum rows values

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql as my database for my application. 
`SELECT max(table1.created_at,table2.created_at) from table`

1.how to Find the maximum values from multiple timestamp columns ?

2.how to add two time stamp value

Answer (score 1):

For question #1:

`SELECT GREATEST(MAX(colA), MAX(colB)) FROM tableName;`

For question #2, read about MySQL time functions:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

**EDIT**

If the two columns are from different tables:

```
SELECT GREATEST(
    (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM table1), 
    (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM table2)
    );
```